# Tuckey UrlRewrite filter doesn't work properly with JSF forms

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I integrated [Tuckey UrlRewrite filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in my JSF application. My URLs now look like:

> http://localhost:8080/myapp/page

instead of

> http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/page.xhtml

The problem is that my JSF forms submits to the old url

> http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/page.xhtml

and I am getting a `FacesFileNotFoundException`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to implement a custom [`ViewHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html) and override the [`getActionURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getActionURL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29) method to return the desired form action URL. That's where the forms get its action URL from. This is by the way also what [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/), the JSF URL rewrite solution, does. You may want to use it instead of reinventing the same wheel. It's by the way open source, so you could just peek around in its source code to see how they did it.

Comment: well, i tried in first place to use prettyFaces but it doesn't support generic url mapping, i have to make mapping for each bean, and even when making mapping for each bean, i get some weird errors about duplicated mapping id.

Comment: The generic URL mapping is still in beta/snapshot stage. You've to report any problems and wait for a final release with those fixes. As to making the separate mappings the normal way, ensure that you aren't using the beta version.

Comment: can you please give me any guesses here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758777/duplicated-mapping-id-with-prettyfaces i posted about this issue on the prettyfaces forum, but they don't have any ideas about such behavior.

Comment: I can't because I have no utter idea how Spring is influential here. I don't use Spring. I just use the standard Java EE stack. Perhaps I can guess if you create a concept **without** Spring (i.e. pure Java EE 6 with PrettyFaces).